# How to make image buttons stay in place when re-sizing web browser

Tags: html, css

This is my image-button for my website.
http://puu.sh/cK7Sf/6309c39cdb.jpg
When I re-size my browser it goes over here
http://puu.sh/cK7VU/f17dafcc41.jpg

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="Nav">
        <div id="buttons">
            <a href="/"><div id="home_button"></div></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#home_button {
background-image: url("home.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
width: 150px;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
top: 196px;
left: 502px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: You should not nest blog elements (like div tags) inside inline elements (like a tags)

Comment: Agreed with @Nillervision ; even if <a> is an exception. You don't need this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`#buttons` div need to have a `position: relative;` set for abosolut position to vork as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to remove "**position: absolute;**" and use **"float: left;"**

Comment: now i cant position the button, cant use the top: and left: codes

Comment: you use the nav div to position all the buttons and you use the float left keep all the button inline to the left. is that what you're going for? when you use position absolute, it takes into account the whole page. when you resize the page it will keep it at the absolute position. the button will not stay inline with the containing div